# ROracle dbwritetable /* APPEND */

Tags: r, oracle, r-dbi

I am doing an ETL (Extract Transform and Load) with a lot of data using ROracle's dbWriteTable but I am unfamiliar with the internals of this function and how it is appending to the tables.

Specifically, I want to know if it's possible to send the Oracle hint "/*+ APPEND *" when doing inserts into tables.

I have been practicing my large data inserts on a development oracle instance and I am constantly filling up the database archive logs and don't want to do the same when moving this data into production.

I have already run sql statments like "ALTER TABLE t1 NOLOGGING;" in order to turn off logging but Oracle needs the additional APPEND oracle hint in order to really turn off the logging.

Additionally, I am trying to avoid turning off archive logging for the whole database during this process as there are other production systems using this database.

Comment: More active thread here: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3675033